# gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin 1.6 breaks gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

If I install gsutil according to https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#install_pypi

then gsutil fails with error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gslib/cs_api_map.py", line 17, in <module>
from gslib.gcs_json_api import GcsJsonApi
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 20, in <module>
from oauth2_plugin import oauth2_helper
ImportError: No module named oauth2_plugin
```

However if I install it according to https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary, i.e.

```
pip install gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin==1.5
```

then it works and oauth2_plugin is found in python

Comment: gsutil 4.3, which will be released shortly, will fix this

Comment: gsutil 4.3 has been released to PyPi and should fix this error.